# I check.js not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, icheck

icheck.js working in chrome and IE but not working in firefox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.check').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.check').on('ifChecked', function () {
                $("#butt").attr("disabled", false);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.check').on('ifUnchecked', function () {
                $("#butt").attr("disabled", true);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

above script not working in firefox
please help me

Comment: you need to include what error you are getting in FF, or at least what leads you to believe it is not working in FF...

Comment: no error when i comment script check box visiable in firefox without style

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if $('.check') element is not inside of button or other HTML attribute.
For me the problem was:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default icheck-button">
<input id="check-all" type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
</button>
```

So i removed button attribute.